# Load UITable Data from another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have two Views:

- UITableViewController (View A)
- UIViewController (View B)

I was wondering, if it's possible to load and setup the table from View B and then segue to View A, when the loading is done. I need this, since the Table View loads Data from Core Data and that takes some time; I would then show a Loading Animation or something. I have a function called `loadData()` in View A, which fetches all Elements from Core Data and then calls `tableView.reloadData()`. 
Does anyone know, how I could implement this? Or should I somehow show the loading View directly from View A with a SubView or something?

Comment: Load data from Core Data in B, give the resulting collection of things to A when preparing for the segue, and then do the normal table view stuff with the collection in A? I mean, I'm not sure what the question here is, is it showing a loading animation or is it avoiding that completely?

Comment: *...loads Data from Core Data and that takes some time*. Really? Appreciable time? Actually loading data from Core Data is pretty fast unless you are loading thousands of records. In this case look for a design to load only the necessary (visible) records from CoreData. For example `NSFetchedResultsController` can manage that on your behalf.

Comment: @vandian it probably takes like 2 or 3 seconds. I fetch the data from CoreData, cache it and then reload the table for each element (should be around 5 cells).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to not think about the specifics but instead, think generally:
You want to move from one VC to another and you have some data that needs to be fetched asynchronically. Let's assume you can't know how long it will take.

My suggestion is to contain all data fetching related to a VC inside that VC itself (or services/facades related to it). So basically you should present the UITableViewController and then have it fetch the data while showing skeleton-cells/spinner/etc.

You want to have separation of concerns which means you don't want your ViewController to handle data related to another view controller.

Think about the following use-case: if you have code to fetch data in the previous VC, before presenting the TVC, what happens when you need to re-fetch the data or refresh something? You will have to duplicate the code in both the VC and the TVC.
That's why it's suggested to keep data fetching inside the view controller that needs it.

If, for some reason, you still want to have your answer for this specific question:
You can have the initial VC create the TVC, but not present it yet, call its methods to fetch the data, and have it send a callback (closure/delegate/etc) when it's done fetching. When the fetching is done, present the TVC.

Here is a quick example:

```swift
class MyTableVC: UITableViewController {
    private var myData: [Int] = []
    
    public func fetchData(completion: () -> Void) {
        //Fetch data asyncly
        myData = [1, 2 ,3]
        completion()
    }
}

class MyVC: ViewController {
    private func loadTableVC() {
        let tableVC = MyTableVC()
        tableVC.fetchData { [weak self] in
            self?.present(tableVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I wouldn't use this due to having tight coupling between the 2 view controllers, but it's always up to you to decide how to design your code.